# Unable to create users with 'customer portal manager custom'

Tags: customer-portal, community

im using developer edition org,in my org I have cloned the profile 'customer portal manager custom' to another profile but not able to create users with that profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create customer portal users, you will have to create a contact against and account and "convert" the contact into a portal user.

Alternately, you can use the self register form (if enabled) to create a portal user.